# Scatterplot with line for non-parametric partial correlation in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, correlation

I'm trying to create a scatterplot to accompany a partial correlation in ggplot2. I completed the partial correlation in pcor.test() from the ppcor package. All variables are continuous.

```
pcor.test(data$comprehension, data$measure, 
          data$age, method = "pearson")

   estimate      p.value statistic  n gp   Method
1 0.3896185 0.0002968104  3.783869 83  1 pearson
```

I have been able to create a scatterplot with regression line for a simple correlation in ggplot.

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = comprehension, x = measure)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = measure), method = lm, se = TRUE, fullrange = TRUE)
```

But I can't find guidance on how to create the scatterplot with a regression line that accounts for the third variable of "age". Age is also a continuous variable.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Edit: clarification that age is a continuous variable.

Comment: Is age a continuous variable? It's hard to draw a regression like for two covariates on a 2D plot. I'm not really sure what you would expect the output to look like,

Comment: Yes, age is also a continuous variable. Perhaps there isn't a useful 2D plot. I was just thinking of something to graphically plot the equivalent of the partial correlation where age is controlled for. I hadn't thought of using a 3D plot. Do you have a recommendation?